# Zend Framework 2 Authentication with DbTable adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

That is my local.php config:

```
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dns' => 'mysql:dbname=xxxx;host=localhost;',
    'username' => 'xxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'port' => 3306,
    'charset' => 'UTF8',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    )
)
```

And that is my authentication code:

```
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
            $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment("SHA2(CONCAT({$salt}, ?, salt), '512') AND active = 1");

            $authAdapter->setIdentity($formData['username'])
                ->setCredential($formData['username']);
```

But when I try to submit login form, zend framework throw this errors:

> File: /var/www/app/vendor/zendframework/zend-authentication/src/Adapter/DbTable/AbstractAdapter.php:331
>   
> Message: The supplied parameters to DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
>
> File: /var/www/html/bookingSystemRewrite/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:244
>   
> Message:Statement could not be executed (3D000 - 1046 - No database selected)
>
> File:/var/www/html/bookingSystemRewrite/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:239
>   
> Message:SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Answer (score 0):

When I debug Pdo Driver Adapter I found where is my problem. 

The first problem was in that order:

```
'dns' => 'mysql:dbname=xxxx;host=localhost;'
```

it must be so :

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=xxxx;host=localhost;'
```

And the second problem was in that order:

```
->setCredentialTreatment("SHA2(CONCAT({$salt}, ?, salt), '512') AND active = 1");
```

it must be so:

```
->setCredentialTreatment("SHA2(CONCAT('{$salt}', ?, salt), '512') AND active = 1");
```